# How many images can I load into a NSMutableArray to show in ImageView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I need to load 150 JPEG images that are 100Kb each, but
I get a memory warnings after loading 110 JPEGs at 60Kb each.

My array is:

```
imagesSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and images are loaded like this:

```
NSString *fileLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", IMAGE_PREFIX, i] ofType:IMAGE_FORMAT];

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileLocation];
[imagesSet addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
```

and

```
show:imageView.image = [imagesSet objectAtIndex:[number intValue]];
```

Is there not enough memory? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why are you loading all of them at once?  Are you displaying them all at once? (I doubt it).  Why don't you load a single image in the "show" method?

Comment: I load them all before the show (to make cache) to make a quick animation later. without the cache is very low FPS.

Comment: Use an MP4 instead of such caveman animation.

Comment: can I set any frame to choice quickly in mp4 movie? can you show example? thank you.

Comment: Till, Im sorry, can you answer for last comment about managing mp4?

Answer (score 1):

You are exceeding the memory of a mobile device by far. Remember that a JPEG image will get decoded after being loaded. To calculate the actual amount of memory needed for a single image, you may run this formula: (width * 4) * height when using an UIImageView.

Comment: On an iPhone 2/3G the total amount of memory available to your app is 22mb, if I recall correctly - that value also includes textures etc. used by the GPU. For 3GS and 4 those values are higher but certainly not within the hundreds of megabytes.